# Browsersync on remote development VM will not work in local browser

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch

Thank you so much for taking the time to check out my little conundrum. This is my first StackOverflow question, so please forgive me if I accidentally leave out something important (I'll add any information that you require if you just let me know).

My issue is this: I have a personal development VM that I use to house all of my application code, including the application's server. I use PuTTY to connect to my development VM, and I forward the port that the **vert.x** application server runs on (which is 7443) to my localhost. Thus, when I connect to the server, I just enter:

https://localhost:7443

in the URL bar of the browser on my local machine. I also use **Gulp.js** to build the UI component and watch my files for changes. Currently, the `gulp watch` task just rebuilds Javascript and CSS bundle files that I link to in my `index.html` file, and I manually reload the browser whenever the bundles are done rebuilding. I recently stumbled upon Browsersync when I was researching live-reload technologies for the browser, and it looks awesome, but I cannot get it to work with my development setup.

Here is my gulp watch task:

```
const browserSync = require("browser-sync").create("browser-sync-server");

gulp.task("watch", () => {
    console.info("=== Initializing BrowserSync Server ===");
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "localhost:7443", // This is my dev server running on port 7443
        open: false // I do not want a new browser to open up when I start BrowserSync
    });

    console.info("=== Listening for changes to reload === ");
    const jsWatcher = gulp.watch(
        myJsFiles,
        { awaitWriteFinish: true },
        ["reload-js"]
    );
    const templateWatcher = gulp.watch(
        myHtmlFiles,
        { awaitWriteFinish: true },
        ["reload-templates"]
    );
    const lessWatcher = gulp.watch(
        myLessFiles,
        { awaitWriteFinish: true },
        ["reload-less"]
    );
});
```

When I start the watch task, in the console I see:

```
Starting 'watch'...
=== Initializing BrowserSync Server ===
=== Listening for changes to reload ===
Finished 'watch' after 126 ms
[Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost:7443
[Browsersync] Access URLs:

       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.1.11:3000

          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.1.11:3001
```

I also forward ports 3000 and 3001 to my local machine so that I can access those endpoints in my browser.

I can get to the Browsersync UI just fine at port 3001 over HTTP, but when I click on the "NEW TAB" button under **Local**, a new tab pops, but the server never loads. It just spins and spins, until finally I get an error in Chrome that says "No data received". Does anyone have any ideas as to what the problem could be? My guess is that is has something to do with the fact that my team's application uses HTTPS for browser access, and that Browsersync needs some further configuration to work with HTTPS, but I do not know how to go about doing this.

Thank you all so much for helping me out! Please let me know if I can provide you all with any more information.

-- Tom

### Edit 5/23/18:

I used `openssl` to generate localhost key and cert files for my development VM, and added them to my configuration for BrowserSync in my gulpfile.js.

Here is my modified config:

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

...

browserSync.init({
  ui: {
    port: 8080
  },
  https: {
    key: "./conf/browsersync/localhost.key",
    cert: "./conf/browsersync/localhost.crt",
  },
  server: {
    baseDir: "./",
    index: "index.html"
  },
  middleware: [
    proxy("/api", {
      target: "https://localhost:7443",
      secure: false, // Do not validate SSL certs
      changeOrigin: true, // Seems to be a highly recommended setting
      xfwd: true,
      prependPath: true, // Ensure that the API calls are prepended with the target URL
      logLevel: "debug" // So that I can see verbose console output
    })
  ],
  port: 3000,
  open: false
});
```

This has definitely gotten me farther, but it is still not quite right. Now, when I hit https://localhost:3000 in my browser, I am taken to the index page of my web application, but none of the asynchronous API calls are getting resolved correctly. In the console where I am running the `gulp watch` task, I see a lot of errors from HPM (the `html-proxy-middleware` software). Here is one example:

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/settings/ from localhost:3000 to https://localhost:7443 (ECONNRESET) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

Also, if I open the Javascript console in my browser window for https://localhost:3000 (the BrowserSync session), I can see lots of 504 errors (Gateway Timeout). Any ideas? Thanks again so much for your time.

-- Tom

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I agree, browsersync is awesome.

`[Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost:7443` Note the http instead of https. This cannot work. In your line `proxy: "localhost:7443"` you are not telling anything about the protocol. Try with a `https://` prefix. Most likely you'll also need the "secure: false" or similar if your development server uses a self-signed certificate. The proxy will have to accept this certificate, not your browser.

If your backend also uses secure-only cookies, you'll have to use https on the browsersync and client side too, or your browser will refuse the secure cookie. Here is my working development config (Gruntfile syntax) doing that:

```
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
[...]
options: {
    port: 3000,
    server: {
        baseDir: './',
        index: '_index.html'
    },
    // redirect all calls to /api to the backend
    https: true,  // required for secure cookie to work
    middleware: [proxy('/api', {
        target: "https://external.backend.server",
        secure: false,  // required if server uses self-signed certificate
        changeOrigin: true,
        xfwd: true  // add X-Forwarded-* headers
    })],
    watchTask: true,
    logConnections: true,
    scrollRestoreTechnique: 'cookie',
    reloadDebounce: 500,
    ghostMode: false
}
```

Comment: Hey @maxy, thank you so much for your detailed response! I implemented some HTTPS options in my browserSync object, so now I have `https: { key: "config/browsersync/localhost.key", cert: "config/browsersync/localhost.crt"}` specified as an option. The .key and .crt files are self-signed SSL key and certificate files that I generated via OpenSSL (by following [this guide](https://deliciousbrains.com/https-locally-without-browser-privacy-errors/)). I am still having the same problems, though. The window just loads indefinitely until I see "No data received." Any other thoughts? Thanks again.

Comment: One more thing: I created an SSH tunnel from my local machine to my dev VM so that all traffic to port 7443 on my computer is redirected to port 7443 on my development VM (so that I can access my development server in my browser by going to https://localhost:7443). Do you think that that is going to pose a problem?